# List does not exist.The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list-view, error, site-column

I have a list view web part in a site page. The view has two site columns. I am getting this error when I access the site page:

**Site Page Error**

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open
>   this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator.
>
> Correlation ID:f071009d-8d2e-b04f-2483-ea487d2a7935

**ULS Log for the Correlation ID**

> InnerException 1:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException:       List does
>   not exist.      The page you selected contains a list that does not
>   exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.

If I remove the site columns from the view, the page has no errors.

Any ideas on what's causing this?

Comment: Is one of the columns maybe a lookup column? If so make sure nothing is wrong with the list it references

Comment: Yes both are lookup fields. However I created a new custom list and added these two site columns. Added a new site page and the list view works fine. I guess the lookup wiring is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I deployed the site on staging to production using site template, I was able to resolve the problem through following approach:

1. Identify which web part is corrupted by removing the webpart from the page in maintenance mode. e.g. http://siteurl/Sites/yoursite/pages/home.aspx**?contents=1**
2. Export the webpart and open in notepad. Check the following line.

   ```
    <property name="ListId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
           D8C4G5A2-17A5-4804-A644-6EB4528DCA42
       </property>
   ```
3. I found that the list id was mismatching. I replaced the list id with correct list id.
4. Replace the id every where in the .WebPart file.

   webpartpages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{D8C4G5A2-17A5-4804-A644-6EB4528DCA42}
5. Replace the weburl every where

   webpartpages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="**weburl**" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="**/sites/YourSite**"
6. Save the file. Go to Edit the page and upload it.
7. After uploading you can add the web part into page.